# What facts are being used in this atomic structure question?

Tags: atomic-structure

I wish to understand how to solve this atomic structure question:

> For the ground state, the electron in the H-atom has an angular
>   momentum = $\hslash$ , according to the simple Bohr model. Angular
>   momentum is a vector and hence there will be infinitely many
>   orbits with the vector pointing in all possible directions. In
>   actuality, this is not true, because:

1. Bohr model gives incorrect values of angular
   momentum.
2. only one of these would have a minimum energy.
3. angular momentum must be in the direction of spin of electron.
4. electrons go around only in horizontal orbits.

Actually, we have been taught Bohr orbits a lot in class, with formulae for everything (atomic radius/electron orbital speed/various energy levels/etc.)  and also basics of the quantum mechanical model. However, we didn't go into such a great depth of Bohr orbits as asked in the above question.

Specifically, I don't know of any reasonable arguments against points 1,2,3. Point 4 is evidently wrong based on the quantum mech model.

> How do I develop any claim for/against the points 1,2,3? What are the facts involved here?

Answer (score 2):

The only correct answer is #1.

In actuality, the ground state of the hydrogen atom has zero angular momentum.

Regarding #2 and #4, there is no preferred plane in which one point should orbit another point.  By symmetry, they are all equivalent.

Regarding #3, there is no angular momentum in the ground state, and in a state whether there is angular momentum, it doesn't need to be in the same direction as the electron spin angular momentum.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please add some detail as to why it has zero angular momentum? And why are points 2 and 3 wrong?

Comment: Oh, I just noticed your elaboration (next time please comment if you update your answer :)) I understand your logic for point 2, 3 and 4. For why there is zero angular momentum, I came across an [old answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112406/why-the-orbital-angular-momentum-equal-zero-for-electron-in-s-state-does-it-mea) by you (coincidence ;))? Does that answer also apply in this question?